# Azure ML Future Prediction Algorithm

Tags: azure, machine-learning, prediction, azure-machine-learning-service

I support a business where customers pays for various services that they use on monthly basis.  I would like to use machine learning based on customers' historical usage of various services and predict the future usage (increase or decrease).

I've used two class to create a model where it uses historical month-1 service usages and month-0 usage to predict the growth or decline. But I would like to start using all historical information not only m-1.

How could I do this? Is my option to keep adding (M-2,M-3,M-4) columns? if that's the case I'm going to have hundreds of columns.

I'm new to machine learning and I'm not sure which algorithm is great for the type of analysis I'm doing.

Here is an example of the original table that I have:

```
Customer Name | MonthName      | Service | Usage
------------- | ---------------|---------|------
Customer1     | January, 2017  |Service2 |$400
Customer1     | January, 2017  |Service1 |$300
Customer1     | January, 2017  |Service3 |$0
Customer1     | December, 2017 |Service2 |$600
Customer1     | December, 2017 |Service1 |$500
Customer1     | December, 2017 |Service3 |$700
Customer1     | November, 2016 |Service1 |$500
Customer1     | November, 2016 |Service2 |$50
Customer1     | October, 2016  |Service1 |$800
Customer2     | January, 2017  |Service2 |$400
Customer2     | January, 2017  |Service1 |$800
Customer2     | December, 2017 |Service2 |$600
Customer2     | December, 2017 |Service1 |$500
Customer2     | November, 2016 |Service1 |$500
Customer2     | November, 2016 |Service2 |$50
Customer2     | October, 2016  |Service1 |$800
```

Here is the table I'm using right now to come up with 2 class model:

```
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
| Customer Name  |  MonthName       | Service1  - M-1 | Service2  - M-1 | Service3  - M-1 | Usage M-1 | Service1  | Service2  | Service3  | Usage | Usage Decline Flag |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
| Customer1      |  October, 2016   |               0 |               0 |               0 |         0 |       800 |           |           |   800 |                  0 |
| Customer1      |  November, 2016  |             800 |                 |                 |       800 |       500 |        50 |           |   550 |                  1 |
| Customer1      |  December, 2017  |             500 |              50 |                 |       550 |       500 |       600 |       700 |  1800 |                  0 |
| Customer1      |  January, 2017   |             500 |             600 |             700 |      1800 |       300 |       400 |         0 |   700 |                  1 |
| Customer2      |  October, 2016   |               0 |               0 |               0 |         0 |      1600 |           |           |  1600 |                  0 |
| Customer2      |  November, 2016  |            1600 |                 |                 |      1600 |       500 |       100 |           |   600 |                  1 |
| Customer2      |  December, 2017  |             500 |             100 |                 |       600 |       500 |       600 |           |  1100 |                  0 |
| Customer2      |  January, 2017   |             500 |             600 |                 |      1100 |       800 |       400 |           |  1200 |                  0 |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Is this not essentially "time series" learning (so you have a sequence of data per customer and want to predict the "next value" in time)?

Answer (score 0):

try this - Here is the code that does convert rows to columns for having sales for previous days - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/CustomModule/Generate-Lag-Features-1 - source code for this - https://gist.github.com/nk773/a2ed7cd0ce8020647f5e7711f749b3b5